# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre XSS Stored y XSS Reflected?

Tags: web, xss

Mi duda es acerca cuales son las principales diferencias entre un ataque **xss reflected** y **xss stored**. Aun no me ha quedado muy claro, ya que me parecen muy similares.

Answer (score 2):

Stored es cuando visitas una página y el código malicioso está ahí.

Reflected es cuando el código lo estás enviando tu en la petición y el servidor te lo muestra de vuelta.

Dom es cuando el código malicioso se ejecuta dentro del Document Object Model.

SelfXss es cuando el código malicioso que escribes solo te afecta a ti y no puedes utilizarlo contra otros.

mXss (mutation) es cuando el navegador interpreta código benigno y lo convierte en código malicioso.

Ejemplos:

Stored:

```
<img src=xD onerror=alert()>
```

Podrías ponerte de nombre de usuario el código y cualquier persona que vea tu perfil se le ejecutaría.

Reflected:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="search" value="<img src=xD onerror=alert()>">
<input type="submit">
```

La página te dice: La búsqueda

```
<img src=xD onerror=alert()>
```

no obtuvo ningún resultado. Ejecutando el código. Normalmente estes ataques se suelen hacer con una redirección desde la pagina maliciosa. En caso de GET:

```
window.location="https://example.com/search.php?search='<img src=xD onerror=alert()>'"
```

Lo cual lleva a un usuario que visite tuWebMaliciosa.com a ser redirigido a la página vulnerable enviando el script al parámetro search.

Y por post suele usarse algo tipo el código:

```
setTimeout(formMalicioso.submit, 1);
```

Esto hace lo mismo que por GET pero los parámetros van incluidos en el cuerpo de la petición. El resultado también es el mismo.

DOM:

```
body.innerHTML=location.href.substr(1);
```

En este caso el código malicioso se incluye en la url y no se envía al servidor.

```
https://example.com/#<img src=xD onerror=alert()>
```

Está vulnerabilidad puede ocurrir en cualquier elemento de la página y se puede explotar de forma similar al reflected en muchos casos.

SelfXSS:

```
curl -a "<img src=xD onerror=alert()>" https://example.com/ver_mi_userAgent
```

En este ejemplo usando un comando (curl es como un navegador por consola) cambias el userAgent. La página se supone que es la típica que te muestra el navigator.userAgent y tanto muestra lo que le pongas. Como los navegadores no permiten modificar navigator.userAgent, teóricamente no tienes forma de utilizar este fallo para atacar a otros usuarios. Si la página mostrase ese userAgent en un apartado tipo: Agentes de usuario recientes: ....
Entonces ya pasaría a ser un stored.
También se conoce como selfXSS aquellos ataques en los que le dicen a un usuario que copie y pege el código que le des en la consola o escriba una url en el navegador usando javascript:alert() y similares.

MutationXSS:
Este fallo es difícil mostrar un ejemplo aplicable. Normalmente son fallos complejos en como los navegadores entienden que parte es CSS, que parte es HTML, cual es Javascript y demás. Normalmente los navegadores hacen cosas muy raras intentando arreglar códigos rotos y pueden interpretar un atributo como javascript ignorando el encoding. Sin ir más alla los exploits de img src onerror funcionan sin comillas porque el navegador se las pone.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, un poco de teoría.

**Ataques XSS almacenados (XSS Stored)**

Los ataques almacenados son aquellos en los que el script inyectado se almacena permanentemente en los servidores de destino, como en una base de datos, en un foro de mensajes, en un registro de visitantes, en un campo de comentarios, etc. La víctima recupera entonces el script malicioso del servidor cuando solicita la información almacenada. El XSS almacenado también se denomina a veces XSS persistente o XSS de tipo I.

**Ataques XSS reflejados (XSS Reflected)**

Los ataques reflejados son aquellos en los que el script inyectado se refleja fuera del servidor web, como en un mensaje de error, resultado de búsqueda o cualquier otra respuesta que incluya parte o la totalidad de la información enviada al servidor como parte de la solicitud. Los ataques reflejados se entregan a las víctimas por otra vía, como por ejemplo en un mensaje de correo electrónico o en algún otro sitio web. Cuando se engaña a un usuario para que haga clic en un enlace malicioso, envíe un formulario especialmente diseñado o simplemente navegue a un sitio malicioso, el código inyectado viaja al sitio web vulnerable, lo que refleja el ataque al navegador del usuario. El navegador ejecuta entonces el código porque procede de un servidor "de confianza". El XSS reflejado también se denomina a veces **XSS no persistente** o XSS de tipo II.

**La diferencia**

En pocas palabras es que un se queda "pegado", del lado del servidor, es decir, afecta a todos los usuarios que llegan a abrir una determinada página que ha sido comprometida mientras que los XSS Reflected son ejecutados porque hubo intervención del usuario "malicioso" al ingresar valores por URL.