# ¿Cual es la Diferencia entre XSS Reflected - XSS DOM - XSS Stored?

Tags: dom, xss

Quisiera saber cual es  la diferencia entre  XSS Reflected - XSS DOM - XSS Stored .

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cual es la diferencia entre XSS Stored y XSS Reflected?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306218/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-xss-stored-y-xss-reflected)